# Arduino: How to covert epoch with milliseconds to epoch

Tags: arduino, epoch

I'm currently downloading a JSON from external source via HTTP. Working without any problem. Afterwards I parse it with ArduinoJson.

```
String payload = https.getString();
const size_t capacity = JSON_ARRAY_SIZE(1) + JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(9) + 210;
DynamicJsonDocument jsonDoc(capacity);
deserializeJson(jsonDoc, payload);
```

Contained in the JSON there is a big number:

```
[{"date":1579459067000,"dateString":"2020-01-19T18:37:47Z"}]
```

Since I need the unixtimestamp w/o millis? I tried with long and double, but the it's just too huge.
How can I convert this big number 1579459067000 to 1579459067, or sould I rather parse the dateString?

In the end I need the number it as long.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `uint64_t` type

Comment: When I try it with the `{"date":1579462666000}`, I get          `Serial.println(PriUint64<DEC>(date));`: 1579462034041 ?! which has a difference of 631959‬ ???

Comment: what is date in 'PriUint64<DEC>(date)'?

Comment: @Juraj `uint64_t date = jsonDoc[0]["date"]`

Answer (score 0):

To work with 64bit integer with ArduinoJson, you must use

```
#define ARDUINOJSON_USE_LONG_LONG 1 // we need to store long long
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
```

I found the information [here](https://arduinojson.org/v5/api/config/use_long_long/) and I tested it for ArduinoJson version 6 on Uno and on esp8266. It works.

```
#define ARDUINOJSON_USE_LONG_LONG 1 // we need to store long long
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

const char* json = "{\"date\":1579459067000,\"dateString\":\"2020-01-19T18:37:47Z\"}";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  StaticJsonDocument<200> doc;

  deserializeJson(doc, json);

  uint64_t t = doc["date"];

  Serial.println((unsigned long) (t / 1000));

}

void loop() {

}
```